# Is it possible to make Eclipse jump to the console upon run, especially when there's input? Also, can I hide the toolbar?

Tags: java, eclipse

In my old IDE, if I'd run a Java file and the console requested input, it would jump my text cursor to it so I could type without moving my mouse. Eclipse doesn't seem to do this. Can I make it?

Also, how do you hide the toolbar? I prefer keyboard shortcuts so it's just cluttering up my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide the toolbar, you can go here: http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-hide-toolbar/
for a plugin which hides the toolbar every time you start eclipse.

I don't think there is a way to have your cursor jump to the input like you described but it's a minor issue when you consider that an average user clicks and moves the mouse thousands of times a day, never mind an active programmer.

But I might be wrong.

Answer (score -3):

Press ctrl+tab thrice and u will be there at Console.......

Comment: that's not an answer to the question, is it;) anyway, please take the time to write real English words (vs _u_)